Execute vulnerability scanning from within an alpine docker container using vuls
I want to run vuls scanner from within an alpine container.
alpine is listed as supported OS.
Since I am within a docker container I want to avoid running vuls as a container itself (to skip the trouble of having to run dind etc)
However when trying to install it:
# pwd
/home/pkaramol/vulsctl/install-host
# ./install.sh
"alpine" is not supported distro, so please install packages manually.

# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Alpine Linux"
ID=alpine
VERSION_ID=3.15.4
PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.15"
HOME_URL="https://alpinelinux.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/"


It's mentioned on the page you linked, but vulsctl's installer doesn't support Alpine. Check this page from the sidebar, it only supports Fedora-based distros (the install.sh file at the bottom lists the specific distros in more detail).
https://vuls.io/docs/en/install-manually.html

3.13 > 3.3 in semver afaik

Yeah that was my bad, I'd misread your output as 3.1.5. I've updated the answer either way, your issue is vulsctl isn't supported on alpine.
